# Imported sprite assets looks different in Unity Game

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics, sprite

Key, somebody know why my character sprite assets looks different in Unity?
How i can fix it?
How my hero looks like in any graphic editor:

[image: In editor]

And how it looks like in Unity:

[image]

Look at that chunk on his head top left, what is it? How to fix it?
I have this issue only on character sprites.

Update 1:
Settings of main sprite file:
[image]

Comment: Can you show the settings the imported sprite uses?

Comment: @Yardi Click on `Advanced` in the editor UI and see if you have anti aliasing turned on. If you do, turn it off.

Comment: The reason was a quality of sprite.